# scrape facebook likes with python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, scrape

I'm trying to scrape Facebook public page likes data using Python. My scraper uses the post number in order to scrape the likes data. However, some posts have more than 6000 likes and I can only scrape 6000 likes, also I have been told that this is due to Facebook restriction which doesn't allow to scrape more than 6000 per day. How can I continue scrape the likes for the post from the point the scraper stop scraping.

Comment: Scraping Facebook is not allowed, and they will block you when they discover it. // When you say more than 6,000 likes, do you mean you need to get the individual likes, i.e. which users liked a post? What for?

Comment: analyzing user behavior for academic research

Answer (score -1):

I am thinking maybe facebook has limited the scraping from the same address which over 6000 times. You can try to use [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) which is a package that used to scrap webpages, it has a component which like a ip pool that can be used for this.

Comment: I was scraping 6000 likes every day for the same address but I lost some likes for the posts which have more than 6000 because after the scraper stopped working I started to crawl a another post next day:(

Answer (score -1):

In tags I see facebook-graph-api, which has limitations. Why don't you use requrests + lxml? It would be such easier, and as you want to scrape public pages, you don't even have to login, so it could be easily solve.